# convertir html a pdf con Html2Pdf

Tags: php, ajax, html2pdf

Lo que quiero es imprimir un archivo pdf con el texto que tengo en Ckeditor
lo obtengo y lo envío con ajax mediante la siguiente función

```
 $('#botontexto').on('click', function() {     
    var texto =  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"texto": texto},
        url:"php/imprimir_informe.php",
        success: function(response){
        },
        complete: function(){
            window.open('php/imprimir_informe.php');
        }
    })   
});
```

y el php que recibe la informacion es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
$html = $_POST['texto'];
$html2pdf = new Html2pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output('prueba223.pdf','D');
?>
```

**El problema es que me genera el archivo PDF en blanco**

Comment: relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134841/822

Comment: la verdad no entiendo lo de la otra publicacion, gracias